# it says > il/elle dit, ceci/cela dit, ou on dit?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, syntaxe

Dans un contexte où on répond à une question en utilisant un texte qui contient les renseignements pertinents, pour exprimer «it says», est-ce qu'on dit:

1. il/elle dit ...
2. ceci/cela dit ...
3. on dit ...

Mon instinct me dit (3), même si cette expression n'est pas une traduction directe de l'expression en anglais. L'usage de (2) me paraît idiomatique en général, et l'expression dans (1) semble approprié seulement si le référent précis a été déjà mentionné (imaginons que la réponse ne mentionne pas le référent même si on peut supposer que le référent est «le texte» ou «la phrase» ou «le paragraphe», etc.)

Comment: Ca dépend. Est-ce que tu peux fournir un peu plus de contexte, ou un exemple?

Comment: @Frank Texte: «Jean aime son travail.» Question: «Est-ce que Jean aime son travail?» Réponse: «Oui, ___ (it) dit que Jean aime son travail.»

Comment: _On dit_: quelqu'un dit, ou bien c'est une rumeur. _Il/elle dit_: une personne spécifique dit cela, peut-être Jean lui-même. _Ceci/cela dit_: impossible ici.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il y a quantité de façons d'exprimer ça. Si on se réfère à un document, un livre, un site :

- Il est dit...
- On y dit...
- Ça dit...
- On peut lire...

*Il/elle dit...* ne sera utilisé que si on vient de parler de la personne qui s'est exprimée.

*On dit...* peut être utilisé si c'est une généralité ou si on se réfère à un document collectif.

*Ceci/cela dit...* est très rarement employé, pas vraiment idiomatique.

On peut aussi souvent indiquer la source comme sujet :

- Wikipédia dit...

ou commencer la phrase par un complément circonstanciel :

- Dans Wikipédia, on peut lire...